# Adding a production database to a Rails 4 site on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Well I've deployed my site on Heroku. When I navigate to the app page it shows a database listed on the Add ons section[image]

I navigate ahead to the database details and this is what I get to see

[image]

This is my production database code

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: dfu332icuvq6bs
  pool: 5
  username: cekapynykihldm
  password: b1XuQq9m1m8Ok3zeyABEgNiiz3
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

My question is when I fill in the details from Heroku into the production database and push it bask to the server, the app doesnt talk to the database as none of my routes except the home#index works. How do I make my app talk to the database on Heroku.

Comment: Heroku rewrites your database.yml file, so there is no reason to edit it yourself.  Your setup looks right.  Try ``heroku ps:restart``.  If that does't work, check the output of ``heroku config`` to be sure that **DATABASE_URL** is set.

Comment: I ran heroku config and Database_url is set
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://kghkevphkflwvw:Y_asCxK_NCloH_5SB3NorUe2J4@ec2-54-204-43-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dd5d862qanokdu

Comment: I though cant navigate to any urls on the site.

Comment: What do you see in ``heroku logs`` when you try visit a valid URL on your site?

Comment: @Troy it goes to a page that says Something went wrong

Comment: Run `heroku logs -t` on the command line to see the rails logs so you can figure out what actually went wrong.

Comment: @Troy indeed everytime I tried a controller action, the error is ERROR -- : PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:...
Thus I guess the schema has not been dumped on the production database.

Comment: I think we've found it!  Please see my answer, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, it appears that you need to run the database migrations and then restart your instance:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku ps:restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess I missed the most important step. I was able to fix the problem by running

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```